# How to delete an object from memory using jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an application in which I have a page for creating a customer. for that I have written following code.

```
customer=new MobileApp.CustomerViewModel(); //for creating new customer
```

I want to delete this object. how can I perform this ??

Comment: delete variableName ;

Comment: Note that JavaScript's `delete` keyword is NOT for deleting contents from memory, it is only for removing properties from within an object. [Read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Note that `delete x;` Will attempt to delete a property `x` that exists in the global namespace object.

Comment: is it a global variable or a local one

Answer (score 17):

Setting `customer = null` will make this enable for garbage collector, given that there is no other valid reference to that object.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete customer;
```

See about [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

`delete` operator removes a property from an object. As `customer` is a property of the global object, not a variable, so it can be deleted

Note : `customer` should be a global one

```
customer=new MobileApp.CustomerViewModel();
delete customer; // Valid one

var customer1=new MobileApp.CustomerViewModel();
delete customer1; // Not a valid one
```

Sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXZBD/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and delete doesn't affect memory: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 3):

Recursively destroy the object as shown below. Tested with chrome heap snapshot that the javascript objects are getting cleared in memory

```
function destroy(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj){
        var property = obj[prop];
        if(property != null && typeof(property) == 'object') {
            destroy(property);
        }
        else {
            obj[prop] = null;
        }
    }
}
```